# Exercise 3 in section 2.2 on Hirsch's differential topology

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

This exercise says:

> Let $$p: M \rightarrow N$$ be a $C^s$ map and $$f: N \rightarrow M$$ a $C^r$ section of $p\ $ (i. e. $p \circ f = id_{N}$). Then we need to show:
>
> If $$1 \le r < s \le \infty,$$ then $f$ can be $C^r$ appoximated by $C^s$ sections.

About this exercise, what I think is to do the  similar argument as in theorem 2.7, that is in Theorem 2.6, it shows $C^s(M, N)$ is dense in $C_S^r(M,N)$ (subscript $S$ denoted strong topology), then we only need to show sets of section is open in $C_S^r(M, N)$, then we are done, but i don't think we can achieve this, because once in case $M = N$, $p = id_M, f = id_M$, then any perturb of $f$ will not satisfy condition of section $p \circ f = id_M$, I am really confused on this exercise now, can anyone help me about this exercise?

Comment: You're correct, but you should notice that in general $p\circ g$ is *close to* the identity when $g$ is close to $f$. Try composing with $(p\circ g)^{-1}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for hints you given, I got some ideas on this exercise

Comment: @TedShifrin The idea is because $C^s(M, N)$ is dense in $C_S^r(M, N)$, then we can find a sequence appoximated $f$ by $g_i$, then we can easily show $g_i \circ (p \circ g_i)^{-1}$ is a sequence of section such that $C^s$ appoximated to $f$. Now new question comes: in question b) in this exercise, we impose $p$ is a submersion and $r$ could be $0$, then $f$ can be $C^r$ appoximated by $C^s$ section, why the above argument can not apply to this question. (I don't know why we need $p$ is submersion, using above argument i did not use this condition)

Comment: I am kinda late to this but I am not interily sure that you would have that $g_i\circ (p\circ g_i)^{-1}\rightarrow f$, I think you would need the $g_i$ to be proper or something..